# Ssl Handshake times out randomly on local server NettyClientHandler

Tags: java, ssl, kubernetes, netty, grpc

Ssl Handler randomly times out, it works 30% of the time and time outs 70%, I am enabling ssl in gRPC hosted on kubernetes, it works without time outs outside the cluster, inside the cluster without time outs but time outs when calling from the container where the server is running

Any help is greatly appreciated, will post more details if needed

```
----------------OUTBOUND--------------------
[id: 0x993a7494, L:/127.0.0.1:51082 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:6868] SETTINGS: ack=false, 
settings={ENABLE_PUSH=0, MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS=0, INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE=1048576, MAX_HEADER_LIST_SIZE=8192}
------------------------------------
2017-10-16 04:26:10/GMT DEBUG io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler:68 -
----------------OUTBOUND--------------------
[id: 0x993a7494, L:/127.0.0.1:51082 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:6868] WINDOW_UPDATE: streamId=0, windowSizeIncrement=983041
------------------------------------
2017-10-16 04:26:22/GMT DEBUG io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler:68 -
----------------OUTBOUND--------------------
[id: 0x993a7494, L:/127.0.0.1:51082 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:6868] GO_AWAY: lastStreamId=0, errorCode=0, length=0, bytes=
------------------------------------
2017-10-16 04:26:22/GMT DEBUG io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler:68 -
----------------OUTBOUND--------------------
[id: 0x8146a138, L:/127.0.0.1:51160 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:6868] SETTINGS: ack=false, 
settings={ENABLE_PUSH=0, MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS=0, INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE=1048576, MAX_HEADER_LIST_SIZE=8192}
------------------------------------
2017-10-16 04:26:22/GMT DEBUG io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler:68 -
----------------OUTBOUND--------------------
[id: 0x8146a138, L:/127.0.0.1:51160 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:6868] WINDOW_UPDATE: streamId=0, windowSizeIncrement=983041
------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE
at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:227)
at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:208)
at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:141)
at com.x.x.x.commons.probes.TestProbesGrpc$TestProbesBlockingStub.liveness(TestProbesGrpc.java:147)
at com.x.x.x.client.TestClient.main(TestClient.java:69)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: handshake timed out
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.handshake(...)(Unknown Source)
2017-10-16 04:26:23/GMT DEBUG io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler:83 - 
[id: 0x993a7494, L:/127.0.0.1:51082 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:6868] Sending GOAWAY failed: lastStreamId '0', errorCode '0', 
debugData ''. Forcing shutdown of the connection.
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
```

Comment: Do you have the SSL handshake output? I think that might give you a clue of what's going on? Use the `-Djavax.net.debug=all` VM option.

Comment: I did that, other than "found trusted certificate" it didn't give me any useful info i.e., where the actual issue is

Comment: what version of grpc are you using?